# Modo de verbo en ke-frazo post "anstataŭ"

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Ŝajne, en ĉiuj frazoj, kie troviĝas la frazparto "anstataŭ [tio,] ke", estas en la ke-frazo verbo en modo indikativa anstataŭ kondicionala. Jen estas ekzemploj el PMEG/Tekstaro.

> Anstataŭ ke ĉiu lernas diversajn lingvojn, ĉiuj ellernadu unu saman lingvon.
> Anstataŭ tio, ke vi estis forlasita kaj malamata [...], Mi faros vin fierindaĵo de la mondo.

Kial ne us-modo? La ke-frazoj tie estas nerealaj, ĉu ne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kial ne us-modo? La ke-frazoj tie estas nerealaj, ĉu ne?

```
Anstataŭ ke ĉiu lernas diversajn lingvojn, ĉiuj ellernadu unu saman lingvon.
```

Tio estis fakto tiam, kaj plu estas fakto nun. Personoj lernas plurajn lingvojn por interkomunikiĝi kun alilingvanoj. Estas nenio imaga...

```
Anstataŭ ke ĉiu lernus diversajn lingvojn, ĉiuj ellernadu unu saman lingvon.
```

Se vi planus aŭ fasonus la mondon (imagu vin dieca) kaj ankoraŭ ne povus decidi ĉu havi plurajn lingvojn kaj komunan ĉu nur plurajn aŭ ĉu nur komunan, en tiu okazo vi uzus la -us formon, dum vi klarigas kiel funkcius unu el la modeloj rilate al alia.

Comment: Mi celis paroli pri la "lernas" tie kaj la "estis forlasita" supre, ne la "ellernadu" aŭ la "faros".

Comment: @MonatheMonad prave, mi estis miskompreninta. Mi ĵus respondis denove.